# Converting Elements in a Dataframe to Columns in a Table

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
$RandArcBo1
$RandArcBo1$x
 [1]  150.5  166.5  135.5  177.5 -146.5  153.5 -152.5  152.5  157.5 -174.5 -155.5 -139.5 -129.5  136.5 -157.5   73.5

$RandArcBo1$y
 [1] 53.56732 78.56732 79.56732 58.56732 73.56732 57.56732 74.56732 55.56732 50.56732 84.56732 82.56732 81.56732 83.56732 78.56732
[15] 73.56732 73.56732

$RandArcBo1$Species
[1] "RandArcBo1"
```

I would like to convert the dataframe to a table in which each dataframe element corresponds to a column in a table, as follows:

```
Species       x             y
RandArcBo1    150.5         53.56732
RandArcBo1    166.5         78.56732
```

..etc.

I have tried using xtabs(), but can't seem to phrase the code in a way that doesn't result in an error, and am also investigating the reshape package, but so far I've been stymied. Any ideas?

Comment: That looks like a list, rather than a data frame. Can you provide the output of `dput()` on the object in question?

Comment: Did you try `as.data.frame(.)`?

Comment: You have a list containing a list. Just do `as.data.frame(dat$RandArcBo1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `data.table` package, it will do the recycling that you seem to want:

```
l = list(x = c(1:10), y = c(11:20), species = "test")

library(data.table)
as.data.table(l)
#     x  y species
# 1:  1 11    test
# 2:  2 12    test
# 3:  3 13    test
# 4:  4 14    test
# 5:  5 15    test
# 6:  6 16    test
# 7:  7 17    test
# 8:  8 18    test
# 9:  9 19    test
#10: 10 20    test
```